# Почему запрос select возвращает только названия столбца?

Tags: python, sql

Есть запрос в DB2:

```
%sql select CASE_NUMBER from CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA where PRIMARY_TYPE = 'OFFENSE INVOLVING CHILDREN';
```

В ответ я должна получить номера дел о преступлениях, которые запрашиваю.
Но получаю только заголовок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Название таблицы, столбца и искомых данных в ячейке я скопировала из самой таблицы.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: Обычно такое происходит, потому что ничего не нашел

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Измените вопрос, добавив текстовую информации текстом. Для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1371369/edit) под самим вопросом.

Comment: стоит указать структуру и небольшой сэмпл данных

Comment: Если убрать из запроса WHERE - данные возвращаются?

Comment: @Akina при этом лучше не забывать что то типа LIMIT 5

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Фигня, клиент разберётся. Главное - уловить сам факт получения записей. А количество... да сколько там тех дел может быть-то? ну миллион, вряд ли больше.

Answer (score 1):

Разобралась)

Методом "научного тыка" выяснила, что тип данных столбца, в котором мне нужно найти записи, varchar15. При загрузке в базу данных всё, что длиннее 15-ти символов, усекается. Поменяла тип данных этого столбца при загрузке таблицы в базу данных не varchar30 и получила искомые номера дел.

Всем спасибо за участие в решении вопроса!

Answer (score 0):

```
select CASE_NUMBER from CHICAGO_CRIME_DATA
 where PRIMARY_TYPE like 'OFFENSE%INVOLVING%CHILDREN';
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: По кофейной гуще определяете данные в таблице?

Comment: Почему например WHERE не написать вот так: PRIMARY_TYPE IN ( 'OFFENSE', 'INVOLVING' 'CHILDREN')